# Вывод всего текста из файла

Tags: c

Я не могу написать часть программы, которая бы выводила весь текст, который есть из файла пользуясь `fprintf` и `fscanf`, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `fprintf` и `fscanf` нет в C#

Comment: сори, не С#, а С

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, зачем вы учитесь на программиста ? Родители настояли ?

Comment: Я не студент, а школьник (если вы об этом), нет, учиться на программиста решил сам

Comment: Если вы хотите стать программистом - тогда и не поленитесь прочитать документацию (и это нужно всегда, если вы не знаете что это такое) А в документации всё очень четко написано про [scanf][1] и [fprintf][2] и подумать как это нужно применить в вашей задаче.


  [1]: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/sprd/fscanf.php
  [2]: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/spru/fprintf.php

Comment: Спасибо, до этого вопроса читал примеры из книги Ритчи, но не особо понял как именно они работают

Comment: @ХэшКод, неужели теперь **школьникам** дают задания по программированию на C ?

@Александр Спичаков, проще всего скопировать файл (ориентируясь на "выводила весь текст") с помощью fprintf и fscanf  посимвольно, т.е. используя формат "%c" в обеих функциях. Вместо EOF проверяете fscanf на 0. 

Впрочем, Вы наверное и сами так проверяете в соответствии с документацией.

@alexlz, Пардон, прочитал Ваш ответ уже после написания своего коммента.

Comment: @avp, в Индии в школах изучают Си, в варианте TurboC.

Comment: А нужно использовать строго fscanf? По мне, это не самое удобное. Лучше читать файл либо по строчкам с помощью fgets, либо почарно с помощью fgetc. Функции семейства scanf надо для другого использовать - для форматированного чтения потоков. Указанные мною функции работают быстрее, а строчку целиком с помощью scanf вообще не прочтешь.

Comment: @avp Видимо у парня преподаватель немного с закидонами, поскольку scanf в программах встречается не очень часто и его особенности многие (я, например) просто забывают. Как-то не относится к знаниям первой очереди. А задач лучше, чем такая, под рукой не оказалось.

Comment: Это наверное задача на внимательность прочтения man fscanf/fprintf.

Comment: Мне над такой задачей подумать прикольно, а парню, начавшему изучать C -- вряд ли. Есть масса вещей, которые требуют усвоения раньше, чем особенности этой процедуры.

Comment: Да, есть дурацкие задачки, а студент переживает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй понять, что тут написано. Если что-то не понятно, задавай вопрос, постараюсь ответить. Задание с подковыркой из-за характера scanf.

Вариант1 (по одному символу):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *in, *out;
    char c;
    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    while(1) {
        fscanf(in, "%c", &c);
        if (feof(in)) break;
        fprintf(out, "%c", c);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Вариант 2 (по 100 символов, если есть, символ `\0` в файле встречаться не должен):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE    *in, *out;
    char    c[101];
    int     n;
    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    while(!feof(in)) {
        fscanf(in, "%100c%n", c, &n);
        c[n] = 0;
        fprintf(out, "%s", c);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```